# Fourier Transformation of 3D Positional coordinates

Tags: python, numpy, deep-learning, scipy, 3d

I have a 3D Shape in voxel format. I want to make use of 3D positional coordinate information to train a neural network. Some papers suggested transforming them using Fourier transformation. Which python library and which Fourier transformation would be best for this task?
What I want to exactly transform is (x,y,z).

I found this code piece from Scipy:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rng = np.random.default_rng()
[X, Y] = np.meshgrid(2 * np.pi * np.arange(200) / 12,
                     2 * np.pi * np.arange(200) / 34)
S = np.sin(X) + np.cos(Y) + rng.uniform(0, 1, X.shape)
FS = scipy.fft.fftn(S)
plt.imshow(np.log(np.abs(scipy.fft.fftshift(FS))**2))
plt.show()
```

I am not sure how to alter the formula When I try to convert this to a 3D toy example as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
rng = np.random.default_rng()
[X, Y, Z] = np.mgrid[:64, :64, :64]
S = np.sin(X) + np.cos(Y) + rng.uniform(0, 1, X.shape) # here is the problematic part
```

Comment: You can do Fourier transformations with [scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/fft.html).

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to choosing a library for computing FFT, it primarily depends on the computational code architecture (parallel, GPU, ...). For basic computations, [NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/routines.fft.html) and [SciPy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/tutorial/fft.html) provide intuitive interfaces for FFT calculations but may quickly reach their limitations when dealing with large datasets.

The following libraries are alternatives for high-performance computations:

- [pyFFTW](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.array.fft.fft.html): This library provides a wrapper for FFTW, which offers better performance compared to the implementation in NumPy. Although this library does not provide a direct parallelization interface, it can be combined with `mpi4py` (see [`mpiFFT4py`](https://github.com/spectralDNS/mpiFFT4py)) for parallelization capabilities.
- [Dask](https://docs.dask.org/en/stable/generated/dask.array.fft.fft.html): This library provides a parallel interface for computations using NumPy/SciPy functions.
- [CuPy](https://docs.cupy.dev/en/stable/reference/fft.html): This library provides a GPU interface for computations using NumPy/SciPy functions.

Here are some benchmark references that utilize different Python libraries:

- [FFT performance using NumPy, PyFFTW, and cuFFT](https://www.johnaparker.com/blog/fft_2d_performance)
- [FFT Speedtest comparing TensorFlow, PyTorch, CuPy, PyFFTW, and NumPy](https://thomasaarholt.github.io/fftspeedtest/fftspeedtest.html)

Comment: Thank you so much for the resources it is very valuable. Can you help me with the 3D conversion of the Scipy code piece? I edited my question.

Comment: @bc_msa Since you transformed the `mgrid` to 3D, `X` and `Y` (and so `S`) are 3D arrays. You could edit the sine wave to also be function of `Z`, but otherwise it's already a valid 3D toy example code.

Comment: S = np.sin(X) + np.sin(Z) + np.cos(Y) + rng.uniform(0, 1, X.shape) Do you mean this? What confuses me is that fft functions outputs complex numbers.

Comment: Fourier transform transfers the signal from the space/time domain to the frequency domain. In the frequency domain, the signal has two properties: magnitude and phase. Complex numbers are used to describe the two properties. Thus, Fourier transforms always output complex numbers.